# Angular safe type operator not working in component

Tags: javascript, angular

i succesfully do this inside my templates

`this.destinyForm.get('category').value?.includes('male')`

Note the `value?.includes` with the safe type operator as the form may not have a value, but when i use the same piece of code in the component.ts i get:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: @DevinFields I have typescript version 2.7.2 and Angular 6, it means that this operator if exclusive of angular when in templates but in the component it depends of typescript?

Comment: Typescript needs to know how to handle this operator when transpiling, so if your version of typescript doesn't yet understand that feature, it will fail to parse. That link I posted is for Typescript 3. You should check your current version to make sure it contains that feature.

Comment: @DevinFields Isn't that just to satisfy the compiler though?  It won't provide the runtime safety that `?.` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?.` is a feature of Angular templating, and is not a part of TypeScript - the two have very similar syntax, but there are some differences, and this is one of them.  That means you can't use it in your component code.  A couple of other ways to do what you want:

The standard way would be to use short-circuit logic to check the possibly missing parts, e.g.

```
this.destinyForm.get('category').value &&
this.destinyForm.get('category').value.includes('male')
```

If `value` is null or undefined, it will return that and not attempt to read the remaining properties. (note - if `get()` has side effects, you'll probably want to call it and store the result in a variable first if you're using this method)

A shortcut that I use in my own app is to use a function to safely access values:

```
function getSafe<T> (func: () => T): T {
    try {
        return func()
    } catch {
        return undefined
    }
}

getSafe(() => this.destinyForm.get('category').value.includes('male'))
```

The way this works is that, by wrapping it in an anonymous function, it doesn't attempt to read the value until the anonymous function is unwrapped inside the `try` block, which will safely catch any TypeErrors if part of the chain is null/undefined.  You can do the same thing with just a regular try/catch, but doing it this way means you don't have to add that to your code over and over. (note - if the value you're accessing can throw another kind of error, this will swallow it silently so make sure to handle that separately if it's important)

Comment: Thank you! it worked great with your try catch solution. I was using that code in an if with 4 other expressions like that so the first option would have been too lenghty